# HTML: Show transparent cover on image and video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a transparent cover when I hover over a `<picture />` or a `<video />`, and hide the cover again when the mouse leaves the image or the video.

**Here is my code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cspn-show-on-hover').hover(

    function() {
      $(this).find('.cspn-cover').css('display', 'table-cell');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find('.cspn-cover').css('display', 'none');
    },
  );
});
```

```css
.cmedia-box {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.cmedia {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.cdiv-show-on-hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cspn-show-on-hover {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0rem;
  left: 0rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.cspn-cover {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: #6b478fb3;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<picture class="cmedia-box">
  <div class="cdiv-show-on-hover">
    <span class="cspn-show-on-hover">
      <span class="cspn-cover"><h1>Hello</h1></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <img class="cmedia" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/25/08/41/books-3348990_960_720.jpg" />
</picture>


<video class="cmedia-box" controls>
  <div class="cdiv-show-on-hover">
    <span class="cspn-show-on-hover">
      <span class="cspn-cover"><h1>Hello</h1></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <source class="cmedia" src="https://cdn.theguardian.tv/mainwebsite/2017/08/04/040717heart_desk.mp4" />
</video>
```

As you may notice, when you hover on the image, a transparent purple cover is shown. But when I used a `<video />` instead of `<picture />`, the cover no longer appears !
Could anyone help me identify the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video elements should be treated as images, where they can't have unrelated children elements. Also, you should be able to make the hover event by just using pure css like so:

```
.cmedia-box:hover .cspn-cover {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

I made it work how you might have intended here:

```css
.cmedia-box {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.cmedia {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.cdiv-show-on-hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.cspn-show-on-hover {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0rem;
  left: 0rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.cmedia-box:hover .cspn-cover {
  display: table-cell;
}

.cspn-cover {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: #6b478fb3;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<picture class="cmedia-box">
  <div class="cdiv-show-on-hover">
    <span class="cspn-show-on-hover">
      <span class="cspn-cover"><h1>Hello</h1></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <img class="cmedia" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/25/08/41/books-3348990_960_720.jpg" />
</picture>


<div class="cmedia-box">
  <div class="cdiv-show-on-hover">
    <span class="cspn-show-on-hover">
      <span class="cspn-cover"><h1>Hello</h1></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <video controls>
  
  <source class="cmedia" src="https://cdn.theguardian.tv/mainwebsite/2017/08/04/040717heart_desk.mp4" />
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.This is exactly what I need !

Comment: Why does the purple cover exceed the photo/video from the bottom ?

Comment: The video controls have their own style properties. But, you can simply add the appropriate z-index on your hover div to make sure all of the controls are covered. (I edited my example to reflect this)

Comment: I tried `z-index=10` on the hover div, but didn't work. I also tried to hide the video controls but the cover still exceeds video area a little bit (unlike image cover)

Comment: Ah, now I see what you are referring to. I believe it has to do with the use of display: table and table-cell. The other examples provided do not have this problem and they do not use this display property.

Comment: I removed the table and table-cell here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149039/html-why-video-cover-exceeds-its-bottom-border

If you are able to give an answer, I will be grateful

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a wrapper:

```css
.media-cover {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.media-cover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #6b478fb3;
  opacity: 0;
}

.media-cover:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="media-cover">
  your media object here...
</div>
```

Here's an example with the media objects centered in a full screen parent:

```css
.media-cover {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center-me {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh; 
  padding: 0 15%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.media-cover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none; /*delete this line to disable interaction with video/picture */
  background-color: #6b478fb3;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s linear; /*delete this line to disable fade effect */
}
.media-cover video, .media-cover picture, .media-cover img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.media-cover:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

picture img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
body {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="center-me">
  <div class="media-cover">
    <picture class="cmedia-box">
      <img class="cmedia" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/25/08/41/books-3348990_960_720.jpg" />
    </picture>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="center-me">
  <div class="media-cover">
    <video class="cmedia-box" controls>
    <source class="cmedia" src="https://cdn.theguardian.tv/mainwebsite/2017/08/04/040717heart_desk.mp4" />
</video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have another relevant question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149039/html-why-video-cover-exceeds-its-bottom-border

If you are able to give an answer, I will be grateful

Comment: It is `block` not `inline-block`. But thanks for your willingness to help !

Comment: Yes, you need to add `display:block` to the media object. Or any `float` (i.e.: `float:left`). If it's inline level it gets a space added after it.

Comment: `@line 25` in the example you can see `.media-cover video, .media-cover picture, .media-cover img {display:block;}`. It's there since I answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```html
<html>

<head>

<style>
div{display:inline-block;}
img,video{height:200px;}
.cover:hover{background:#fff;opacity:0.15;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="cover">
<picture class="cmedia-box">
  <img class="cmedia" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/25/08/41/books-3348990_960_720.jpg" />
</picture>
</div>

<div class="cover">
<video class="cmedia-box" controls>
  <source class="cmedia" src="https://cdn.theguardian.tv/mainwebsite/2017/08/04/040717heart_desk.mp4" />
</video>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you know why does the cover exceed the bottom boundary of the photo/video a little bit ?

Comment: I have another relevant question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149039/html-why-video-cover-exceeds-its-bottom-border

If you are able to give an answer, I will be grateful