# HTML: why video cover exceeds its bottom border?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I am trying to show a purple cover over the `<video>` element, but I don't know why the cover exceeds the video bottom border a little bit. Here is my code:

```css
.media-cover {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.media-cover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #6b478fb3;
  opacity: 0;
}

.media-cover:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

video {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="media-cover">
  <video class="cmedia-box" controls>
  <source class="cmedia" src="https://cdn.theguardian.tv/mainwebsite/2017/08/04/040717heart_desk.mp4" />
</video>
</div>
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: I think, you should add CSS: video { display: block; }

Comment: @Sergej post it as an answer, since it's correct

Comment: It is `block` not `inline-block`, but thanks for your willingness to help !

Comment: @Sergej Thanks, you solved my problem. But could you please write it as an answer for people to reach it easily ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All inline elements can safely be considered *letters* in document flow. When you type `a b c`, you expect the browser to render the spaces between your letters.

Similarly, with inline elements, the browser renders the spaces around them (`video` has a default `display` value of `inline`):

```
<div class="media-cover">
   <video class="cmedia-box" controls>...</video>
</div>
```

... will render such a space after the element, before the `</div>` is closed. To tell the browser not to render it, you have multiple options:

**a)** don't add a space there:

```
<div class="media-cover">
   <video class="cmedia-box" controls>...</video
></div>
```

Note there's not space between the ending of video tag `>` and beginning of closing `</div>`.

**b)** give the `display:inline` a block level value (setting `display:block` on `video` will fix it.

**c)** float the inline element (i.e.: `float:left` on `video` will fix it.

Comment: Is there anyway to enforce removing this space ?

Comment: @Ahmed `video{display: block}` should do it (**b)**).

Comment: But according to this code: https://codepen.io/Ahmed_Hussein/pen/rvKGXG, I need `display: block`, `float: none` in order to align columns vertically to be in the middle. As you see, the columns exceed the bootstrap row

Comment: There are multiple techniques to vertically center. Give me a link to a pen/fiddle, tell me what you're trying to achieve and I'll show you how to do it.

Comment: I am trying to align bootstrap columns vertically to be in the middle of the row. In order to understand what I mean, I added two bootstrap rows: one without column alignment and the other with columns aligned to middle of the row. As you see, this makes the columns exceed the row. Here is my code https://codepen.io/Ahmed_Hussein/pen/rvKGXG

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with current question.

Comment: The idea in your answer helped me and solved my issue in the question. I am now having a similar issue in a new code, but I cannot use your answer in my new code because I need both `display: block` and `float: none`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170963/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-ahmed-hussein).